# AppClip easy way to target all needed files

Tags: swift, xcode, apple-appclips

I am building AppClip app based on existing project. My question is - Is there an easy way to target all files which my couple of screens are depending on?

For example
I need add `OrderViewController` to an AppClip. This screen depends from `OrderViewModel`. `OrderViewModel` depends from `BaseViewModel` and `NetworkManager`. And so on, and so on, and so on...

By "depends from" I mean `File_A` using inside code from `File_B`. And to compile a target with `File_A` I need to include `File_B` too, to a target. And as you can imagine there might be a lot of dependency files. But I am lazy. And looking for some magic ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the files you need (OrderViewController, OrderViewModel, NetworkManager ...etc ) in your targets like the Main app and the app clip like that

[image]

then define the custom compilation conditions with any name you like in my case I made it

> APPCLIP

[image]

after that use (compiler directives) to differentiate between the main app and app clip like that

```
#if !APPCLIP
 extension AppDelegate:MessagingDelegate{

}
#endif
```

in the main app, I use MessagingDelegate but in the app clip I don't so, I write a case to check if the app is running app clip or main app

here are some resources that could help you

1. https://needone.app/compiler-directives-in-swift/
2. https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-build-an-app-clip-on-ios-14-a5045fd68eb4
3. https://medium.com/swlh/ios-14-app-clips-95bfaf2b159c